# Expression of the n-th derivative

Tags: combinatorics, derivatives, stirling-numbers

Find an exact expression for the n-th derivative of the function $f(x) = e^{e^{x}}$.

I took a few derivates of the expression and found out that a pattern emerges such that the n-th derivative will be expressed as 
$$S(1, n)* e^xe^{e^{x}} + S(2,n)*e^{2x}e^{e^{x}} + S(3,n) * e^{3x}e^{e^{x}}+ S(4,n) * e^{4x}e^{e^{x}} +.... +S(n,n) e^{nx}e^{e^{x}}$$

where S(n,k) is a Stirling number of the second kind.

My question is how would I find the exact expression? Do I have to prove this someway?

Comment: Typically, we use [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula)

Answer (score 0):

Once you suspect this pattern, namely that $$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left[e^{e^x}\right] = e^{e^x} \sum_{k=1}^n S(n,k) e^{kx},$$ then a proof by induction would be a natural choice for demonstrating its validity.  (I have used the more standard ordering $S(n,k)$ rather than your $S(k,n)$.)

You may also be interested in the [Touchard polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials).

Comment: Thanks, that is what I suspected but just wanted to make sure